# How to get to 10 records from datatable when you press the next and previous in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

datatable code

```
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand comand = new OleDbCommand("Select id, name From menu where KlassID=@KlassID", connection);
            comand.Parameters.Add("@KlassID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = KlassID;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(comand);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);
```

**Button Next**

`private void btNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//enter code here
}`

**Button Previous**

`private void btPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//enter code here`
}

I found a similar [code](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/18702-Code-for-next-previous-first-last-records.aspx) but here is with one record

Comment: Do you want some sort of paging? also another question is its good to get the desired records from DB rather than grab them once and split them individually.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/14/sql-server-tricks-for-row-offset-and-paging-in-various-versions-of-sql-server/)

Comment: To answer your question we need to know which `RDBMS` and data access technology are you use. Add appropriate tags to question.

Comment: You can look into .Take() and .Skip() which are linq extension methods that do exactly what you're looking for. IMO, I think you should use an ORM that uses linq but it's up to you; look into linq-to-EF and that should save you a lot of time.